# obtain query parameter and display details based on parameter

Tags: javascript, html

so with my code: I have an ajax call to get some data from a json file. then with javascript I have a function to display that data.

what im trying to do is have 1 page (game.html) which displays a game based on which game you select. but im having trouble trying to write up the code to handle the query parameter so wondering if any of you could assist.

heres the function:

```
const displayNewOutput = (newReleased, hasCheckbox) => {    
    let Newoutput = "";

    newReleased.forEach(game => {   
        if (game.Type === "New Release" && game.ID <= 3) {
            let ratingDiv = $("<div class='rating'></div>");

            for (var i = 0; i < game.Rating; i++) {
                ratingDiv.append('<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>');
            }
            for (var i = game.Rating; i < 5; i++) {
                ratingDiv.append('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>');
            }

            Newoutput += `
              <li>
                <li>
                   <a class="newGame" href=${game.link}?id=${game.ID}> 
                       <img class="frontGames" src="${game.image}">
                       <p>
                           <b>Name:</b>${game.Name}<br>
                           <b>Release Date:</b>${game.ReleaseDate}</br>
                           <b>Genres:</b>${game.Genres}</br>
                           <b>Retail Price:</b>${game.RetailPrice}</br>
                           <b>Rating:</b> ${ratingDiv.html()}</br>
                       </p>
                   </a>
              </li>`;
        }

        function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
        }

        var tech = GetURLParameter('id');   
        console.log(tech);
    })

    return Newoutput;   
});
```

this line in particular is where the query parameter is:

```
<li><a class="newGame" href=${game.link}?id=${game.ID}><img class="frontGames" src="${game.image}">
```

I've looked at other threads in regards to query parameters but dont understand one bit at all.

Comment: "I have an ajax call", where?

Comment: i didnt think adding it would be necessary, but I can if want

Comment: What don't you understand? The GetURLParameter function, or the concept of query parameters itself?

Comment: the reason being: im trying to focus on the query parameters

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude both, as you can ive attempted it. but im unsure of how to properlly get that parameter and then display the result